# Using a ViewModel for AppShell in .NET MAUI App

Tags: maui

Are we not able to use a `ViewModel` for `AppShell` in a .NET MAUI app using .NET 7?

I did this successfully in a .NET MAUI using .NET 6 but now it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what I'm doing with a `ViewModel` for `AppShell`.

There are two key functions that I have in the `Flyout` of my app: first, I display user's image in `FlyoutHeader` and in `FlyoutFooter`, I have a sign out icon that allows user to log out of the app.

My solution for this was to bind the `AppShell` to its own `ViewModel` i.e. `AppShellViewModel` and use a property for the user's image URL. I also added a function that I call when user taps on `Sign Out` icon in `FlyoutFooter`.

This has worked fine when my .NET MAUI app ran on .NET 6 but ever since I switched to .NET 7, I can neither see user's image nor can I sign out. I placed a break point for the `SignOut()` function in `AppShellViewModel` but tapping the sign out icon doesn't seem to hit the `SignOut()` method.

Here's the `AppShellViewModel`:

```
public partial class AppShellViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public AppShellViewModel()
    {
        // Once user logs in, we get the avatar URL thru MessagingCenter
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "avatarUrlUpdated", (url) =>
        {
            avatarUrl = url;
        }
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    string avatarUrl;

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task SingOut()
    {
       // Handle user sign out
    }
}
```

And we bind this to `AppShell` in code behind:

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
   AppShellViewModel _vm;
   public AppShell(AppShellViewModel vm)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       _vm = vm;
       BindingContext = _vm;
   }
}
```

Again, this is the same code that worked fine when the app was targeting .NET 6. Now, neither the avatar updates nor can I tap to sign out. Any idea what's going on here?

BTW, In `MauiProgram.cs`, I do add both `AppShell` and `AppShellViewModel` to DI container i.e.

```
services.AddSingleton<AppShell>();
services.AddSingleton<AppShellViewModel>();
```

Comment: instead of *describing* your code, please post the *actual* relevant code

Comment: I didn't think the code would add any value to the question but I updated the original post. What's puzzling is that it seems as if the binding isn't working.

Comment: **1)** I don't use AppShell much; is there any xaml/c# associated with *"tapping the sign out icon"? If so, add that code. **2)** Since it worked before, I assume `SingOut` is just a typo for `SignOut`? **3)** Probably not relevant, since it is a different command, but should `avatarUrl = url;` instead be `AvatarUrl = url;`, to trigger any binding?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm nuget package? If so, the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm/8.0.0#supportedframeworks-body-tab) does not currently support .NET 7.

Comment: I posted a question on Twitter and multiple people -- including someone from Microsoft team -- are telling me that this is not an issue. https://twitter.com/SamUresin/status/1594948827899121664

Comment: Can you tell me the version number of VS you are using? It seems that someone in github had a similar problem ([MenuFlyoutItem command binding not working in submenu items](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10734)), which was resolved by updating the VS version.

Comment: VS 17.4 on Windows 11 w/ latest updates/patches

Comment: You can try to use the VS 17.4.0 Preview 4 version mentioned in the above github to see if there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to bind an signout button on the appshell footer to a command in another viewmodel.

I solved it by adding `this.BindingContext = new LoginPageVM();` to the `appshell.xaml.cs` to access the signout command from `LoginPageVM`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `MauiProgram.cs` your registration of services, should go something like:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppShell>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppShellViewModel>();
```

However, there is no constructor injection for `AppShell()` because `App.xaml.cs` explicitly calls `new AppShell()` without any constructor parameters.

```cs
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new AppShell();
}
```

There are two workarounds to this, (1) call `new AppShellViewModel()` or, (2) use dependency injection with a direct call `GetService<AppShellViewModel>()` via a helper:

```cs
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    AppShellViewModel _vm;

    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _vm = new AppShellViewModel();
    }
}
```

or

```cs
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    AppShellViewModel _vm;

    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _vm = IPlatformApplication.Current.Services.GetService<AppShellViewModel>();
    }
}
```